# Multiple ID selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a segment of code as follows

```
$('#go-back').click(function () {
    flipStep(currentStep - 1);
});
```

So when I click anything with the id of go-back it'll run my function flipStep, however when I click anything but the first element with the id of go-back it doesn't work? Why is this? How do I fix it?

Comment: IDs have to be unique. Use class attributes instead.

Comment: Not sure why this question is getting upvoted, but Pekka's right; you need to use classes, like `<thing class="go-back">...`, `$('.go-back').click(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you need to select all element id equals  with *go-back*

```
$('[id$="go-back"]')).click(function () {
    flipStep(currentStep - 1);
});
```

[attribute-ends-with selector ([attr$=value])](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

If id condins any where then you can try

```
$('[id$*="go-back"]')).click(function () {
    flipStep(currentStep - 1);
});
```

If id starts with then you can use

```
$'[id$^="go-back"]')).click(function () {
    flipStep(currentStep - 1);
});
```

[Id starts with selector Multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Great if you need more explanation let me know happy scripting ...

Answer (score 1):

**IDs have to be unique**.

HTML4 specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html (Section 7.5.2):

> id = name [CS]
>       This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

HTML5 specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.